# Deleted Documents folder doesn't show up anymore iOS-HELP (File App)

Tags: ios, icloud

**In the "File" App from my *iPhone 7*.**

I deleted the **default "*Document*" folder** by accident and it doesn't show up in the recently deleted or anywhere else on my *iOS* devices.

**In my Mac shows up no problem.**

I tried to re-sync iCloud on iOS' settings but after 1-2 mins same thing as before.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  iOS doesn't have folders so what do you mean by 'Document' folder?  Can you please [edit] your question to explain exactly what you did, step by step?

Comment: Done, it was obviously on the Files app! And I think only if you are synced with a Mac but yes, Document folder exists on iOS.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me the way your question was written, hence my question.  The folder is inside an app, which is different than on a Mac, so, again, it wasn't clear.   Usually syncing occurs only several times a day so it's possible you didn't wait long enough for the sync?

Comment: The only way to have a stock folder on iOS is with the File app, it is a stock app and also syncs with iCloud. Talking about iCloud i thought it was obvious. Anyway i corrected made it even more clear and answered my own question for helping other that are facing the same problem as me. Yes it was a syncing problem :)

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer and I'm glad you were able to resolve the issue.  You're a new user to this site, but on other SE sites, and we get many, many questions where users mix up mac and iphone features so I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

**After a while without doing anything manually iCloud will do an automatic re-sync and the Documents folder will reappear!** So no problem, just *10-20 minutes* and done!

**If it doesn't show up** in 1 hour or so, try to "*manually re-sync*" iCloud by using the switch in the Setting on one of you iOS devices.
So:
**Settings>"Your name">iCloud>*scroll down*>iCloud Drive**
Switch **OFF** and **ON** **one time**, and then wait again for 10-20 minutes (slower the internet, slower the sync).